# DateTime within interval in JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there a API method in JodaTime to see whether a DateTime is within [start, end], i.e. the boundary is included?

Only thing I found was 
new Interval(start, end).contains(dateTime) but this seems to give false if dateTime equals end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to create a new interval which is the old one extended by a millisecond if you need to do this often:

```
Interval inclusiveInterval = interval.withEndMillis(interval.getEndMillis() + 1);
```

Alternatively just use

```
if (interval.contains(dateTime) || interval.getEnd().isEqual(dateTime))
```

(The `isEqual` method ignores chronology and time zone.)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the latter one before you answered. Thanks anyway, I didn't notice that isEquals behaves like that.

Comment: By the way: is there a logical reason why the contains method doesn't count a DateTime as included in the interval when it's equal to the end DateTime? It seems strange to me.

Comment: @BloodySmartie: Intervals in computer science and maths are often given in a "lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive" way - for one thing, it means that if you have intervals [a, b), [b, c), [c, d) etc that gives you abutting intervals naturally.

Comment: Why use anything but `interval.contains(...)`?